# to change magento admin invoice format

Tags: php, magento

i am working on magento version 1.8.0 and trying to change the default magento printing format of invoice. i have tried to make changes in abstract.php &  invoice.php but if i am creating my custom function in abstract and calling it in invoice,changes do not reflect. kindly help,if there is other way to make custom changes in it.

any help will be appreciated. kindly,don't tell to use any extensions as my client is not going to pay a single penny for it.i just want to edit this initially, then want to change complete layout.

```
 protected function insertAddress(&$page, $store = null)
{
    $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
    $font = $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
    $page->setLineWidth(0);
    $this->y = $this->y ? $this->y : 815;
    $top = 815;
    foreach (explode("\n", Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/identity/address', $store)) as $value){
        if ($value !== '') {
            $value = preg_replace('/<br[^>]*>/i', "\n", $value);
            foreach (Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
                $page->drawText(trim(strip_tags($_value)),
                    $this->getAlignRight($_value, 130, 440, $font, 10),
                    $top,
                    'UTF-8');
                $top -= 10;
            }
        }
    }
    $this->y = ($this->y > $top) ? $top : $this->y;
}

/**
 * Format address
 *
 * @param  string $address
 * @return array
 */
protected function _formatAddress($address)
{
    $return = array();
    foreach (explode('|', $address) as $str) {
        foreach (Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($str, 45, true, true) as $part) {
            if (empty($part)) {
                continue;
            }
            $return[] = $part;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: First find out if the email template is being loaded from file or backend transactional email. If laoded from file, you might directly change codes there rather than editing core files. Secondly, clear CACHE, or disable it for development.

Comment: i am bit confused. printing format is another thing, is there any link between printing invoice and email-templates.kindly,suggest

Comment: i think you haven't got my question. transactional mails are different topic.

Comment: Done it myself finally :)